# Foreach loop only display one item for specific rows on CSV export

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I'm pulling data from Magento and am exporting it to a CSV, the data includes order number, items, sub total and more. The export splits the rows by 'product' and groups them by the 'order ID' which is causing things like the 'sub total' to be duplicated. Is there a way to stop this. It's easier to explain in the code, please see below - the items with *ONLY SHOW ONCE* should only be generated on the first row of that order.

```
foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $orderItem) {
                    $orderData = [
                        (new \DateTime($order->getCreatedAt()))->format('Y-m-d'),
                        $order->getIncrementId(),
                        ($invoice->getCreatedAt())?(new \DateTime($invoice->getCreatedAt()))->format('Y-m-d'):null, //Invoice Date.
                        $invoice->getIncrementId(), //Invoice No.
                        $billingAddress->getName(), //Billing Name
                        $shippingAddress->getCountryId(), //Shipping Country
                        $this->formatPrice($order->getSubTotal() + $order->getDiscountAmount()),//Subtotal ***ONLY SHOW ONCE***
                        $this->formatPrice($order->getShippingAmount()), //Shipping
                        $this->formatPrice($order->getTaxAmount()), //Taxes
                        $this->formatPrice($order->getGrandtotal()), //Total
                        $this->formatPrice($order->getDiscountAmount()), //Discount Amount
                        $this->formatPrice($order->getTotalRefunded()), //Refunded Amount
                        $orderItem->getSku(), //Lineitem sku
                        $orderItem->getName(), //Lineitem name
                        round($orderItem->getQtyOrdered()),//Lineitem quantity
                        $this->formatPrice($order->getSubTotal() + $order->getDiscountAmount()),//Lineitem price
                        $order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getTitle(),//Payment Method
                        $invoice->getTransactionId(),//'Payment Reference'
                ];
                $orderCsv = implode(",", $orderData);
                $file->write($orderCsv . PHP_EOL);
            }
```

Obviously, since the rows are split by the product name some items need to be shown on all rows such as the 'product price'. This is obviously only part of the code but I though it was too long to paste it all in.

Comment: Can’t tell what you are actually looping over there - is this the items of one single order, or multiple orders?

Comment: So it exports all orders over a certain time period and splits them out by line item (products), they are grouped by the order ID. So for example order 1023 will have 3 products in the order so will create 3 lines in the csv.

Comment: So implement a classic _control break_ then - compare the current order ID with that of the previous record, and depending on whether they differ or not, react accordingly.

Comment: I looked at using a break but it then just stops the output after one order. I'm unsure how to continue once a new order number is found.

Comment: Are you talking about the `break` keyword? No one said anything about that. A _control break_ is a basic algorithmic principle.

Comment: I was talking about that yes, ok thank you I'll look into that - I'm fairly new to all this.